# Is the way to show two sequence are the same?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose this pattern $$1, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 25, 29, 31, 35, 37,...$$ I find Two sequences that shows this pattern .
$$a_n=\frac{(6n+(-1)^n-3)}{2} \tag{1}$$and
$$b_{n+3}=b_{n+2}+b_{n+1}-b_{n}  \tag {2}$$ both of them work here .
Is there a way to show (1),(2) are the same ?
 1.Without writing $1, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 25, 29, 31, 35, 37,...$

2.Without find recursion formula of $b_n$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have a recursion formula like you already do for $b_n$, and a closed form, like you do for $a_n$, the easiest way to check whehter they describe the same sequence is induction, which practically amounts to inserting the closed form formula into the recursion formula, and check whether the two sides are equal.

Comment: Have you checked $a_{n+3}=a_{n+2}+a_{n+1}-a_n$?

Comment: @drhab :You think there is a problem ?

Comment: No, but isn't that a logical step if you want to know whether $a_n=b_n$? If both sequences have the same recurrence formula then you are almost there. Completion of proof by showing that $a_1=b_1$.

Comment: From $(2)$, writing $b_{n+3}-b_{n+2}=b_{n+1}-b_{n} $ helps a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$a_{n+2}+a_{n+1}-a_n=$$$$\frac12[(6n+12+(-1)^{n+2}-3)+(6n+6+(-1)^{n+1}-3)-(6n+(-1)^n-3)]=$$$$\frac12[6n+9+(-1)^{n+3}-3]=a_{n+3}$$

So $(b_n)_n$ and $(a_n)_n$ have an equal recurrence relation.

Then $a_1=b_1\wedge a_2=b_2\wedge a_3=b_3$ is enough to conclude that the sequences are the same.

This is formally proved by induction: $$a_n=b_n\wedge a_{n+1}=b_{n+1}\wedge a_{n+2}=b_{n+2}\implies a_{n+3}=b_{n+3}$$

Answer (score 0):

I tried induction. It works fine !

It is now your turn to prove:

If $a_1=1, a_2=5, a_3=7$ and $a_{n+3}=a_{n+2}+a_{n+1}-a_n$ for $n \ge 1$, then

$a_n=\frac{(6n+(-1)^n-3)}{2} $  for all $n$.

Answer (score -1):

$$a_n=\frac{(6n+(-1)^n-3)}{2} \\a_{n+1}=\frac{(6n+6-(-1)^n-3)}{2}\\
a_{n+2}=\frac{(6n+12+(-1)^n-3)}{2}\\
a_{n+3}=\frac{(6n+18-(-1)^n-3)}{2} $$now you can put tehm to check ,is the $$b_{n+3}=b_{n+2}+b_{n+1}-b_{n}  \tag {2}$$ correct ?